# The socket connection to localhost failed

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using Xampp for developing a web using php and MySQL. I am new in this and when I am starting the admin of my Apache and MySQL it gives me an error i.e.

```
[Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80
```

How can I fix this error?

my error log is

```
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:56.435415 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:56.872940 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:56.966694 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:56.966694 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:56.966694 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:56.997952 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2816
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 2816:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:59.326174 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2816:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:02:59.654315 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2816:tid 396] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.534498 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.675145 2015] [core:warn] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.862638 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.940762 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.940762 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.940762 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:02.987647 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1396:tid 408] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3988
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:05.237745 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3988:tid 412] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:05.612764 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3988:tid 412] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 01:08:05.706523 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3988:tid 412] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 24 01:31:46.976420 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jun 24 01:31:49.007777 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2816:tid 396] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jun 24 01:31:49.648419 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2460:tid 388] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2816 exited successfully.
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:07.275528 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2984:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:07.619288 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2984:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:09.650651 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2984:tid 396] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:09.650651 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2984:tid 396] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:09.650651 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2984:tid 396] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:09.666277 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2984:tid 396] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1392
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:11.400745 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1392:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:11.682008 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1392:tid 396] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 24 11:40:11.807018 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1392:tid 396] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: In some configurations you can use in your config `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Also my port no for apache is 8080 and 4433 bcoz i am using another application at port 80 and 443. port no for mysql is 3306.

Comment: There is your answer, define the correct port in the php file. Look into http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp